# Pointer value gets randomly reassigned in a tree problem

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree

In a normal tree problem, let's say there's a function fun.

```c
void fun(Node **root)
{
    printf("%p\n", *root); // here it prints a non nil memory address
    if (*root == NULL || (*root)->left == NULL)
        return;
    Node *p = (*root)->left;

    p->parent = (*root)->parent;
    printf("%p", *root); // here it prints root as nil
    //...
}
```

In which case could this happen, considering that tree contains only 3 2 1, with all of them being added to the left.

Here's the minimal reproducible code sample:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *left, *right, *parent;

} Node;

void fun(Node **root)
{
    printf("%p\n", *root); // here it prints a non nil memory address
    if (*root == NULL || (*root)->left == NULL)
        return;
    Node *p = (*root)->left;

    p->parent = (*root)->parent;
    printf("%p", *root); // here it prints root as nil
    //...
}
void fun1(Node **root)
{
    if (*root && (*root)->parent && (*root)->parent->parent)
    {
        fun(&((*root)->parent->parent));
    }
}
void add(Node **root, Node *parent, int data)
{
    if (*root == NULL)
    {
        *root = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        (*root)->data = data;
        (*root)->left = (*root)->right = NULL;
        (*root)->parent = parent;
        fun1(root);
        return;
    }

    if (data < (*root)->data)
        add(&((*root)->left), *root, data);
    else if (data > (*root)->data)
        add(&((*root)->right), *root, data);
}

int main()
{
    Node *root = NULL;
    add(&root, NULL, 3);
    add(&root, NULL, 2);
    add(&root, NULL, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `fun1` calls `fun`, the `root` parameter of `fun` is pointing to the `parent` member of the node with data 2.

That `parent` member points to the node with data 3. So `*root` points to the node with data 3. And `(*root)->parent` is a null pointer.

In `fun`, `Node *p = (*root)->left` sets `p` to point to the left child of `(*root)`, which is the node with data 2.

Then `p->parent = (*root)->parent;` sets `p->parent` to a null pointer. Since `p` points to the node with data 2, `p->parent` is the `parent` member of the node with data 2, and  that is what `root` points to.

Comment: So in the end, what happens with root? Why does it get modified? I agree with everything you said till the last sentence. What is what that root points to? It doesn't get reassigned, since ```p->parent = k;``` doesn't make root point to k, what's with the null then?

Comment: @Vojin: `root` points to the `parent` member of the node with data 2. So `*root` is the `parent` member of the node with data 2. So when `p->parent = …` changes the `parent` member of the node with data 2, it changes `*root`.